# Files pointed at wrong commit

Tags: git

I have no idea what happened but I think somehow another developer overwrote my commits with their merge. I think the visual studio git plugin botched something.

**Edit**
I think what happened is the other developer merged an old outdated version of the branch that didn't have my changes yet. So now his old commit is being used instead of mine.

I have files I updated with commit `a` but after his merge and push all the files are pointed at another older commit `b`

commit `a` is still in the history but git I guess thinks the head of the file is at commit `b`

Is there an easy way to fix this issue to get all of my files that I updated back to my commit but leave his files he updated intact?

**Edit**
Ascii graph with annotation of what I think happened denoted by <-- {message}.
please correct me
https://gist.github.com/oneillc-advisory/cd039838448bf41e1e22f3a1ff5a4dfc

Comment: Can you share ASCII representation of the log graph?

Comment: `somehow another developer overwrote my commits`. Luckily Git doesn't ever lose history, at least not like that.

Comment: @MadPhysicist yea overwrote is a bad word. They have made git think they are not as important as they once were I guess is a better way of saying it.

Comment: @choroba. sure can is there a preferred place to place upload a text file?

Comment: @choroba I made a gist and included the link in the original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I don't know if this was the best way but I ended up following this http://www.programblings.com/2008/06/07/the-illustrated-guide-to-recovering-lost-commits-with-git/

I performed a rebase from the commit I wanted. That got me about 60% of the way there. The rest I just ended up doing a bunch of merges and hand edits to get things back to where I think they should be. There is probably a much faster and more efficient way to do this but I think i'm like 99% back to where I need to be.

Answer (score 3):

If you still have the correct commit locally you can create a new branch so your commit stays safe, then checkout the original branch, pull so you get the other developer's changes, then merge the new branch you created into that, fixing any conflicts you may have:

```
git checkout -b fix-commit //creates a new branch with your commit on it
git checkout master //assuming the problem is on master
git pull
git merge fix-commit
git push
```

Comment: I tired this but the branch already has the commit in it that contains all my changes so when I merge it tell me that it is already up to date.